# mongodb data is playing in the form of id: ObjectId

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a MEAN Crud project.. I am testing to make sure controller received the new data from the database.. the data was received in the mongodb but displaying in objectId here in the below image

[image: here is the image]

and also the added data is not getting displayed in the localhost.. its displaying like this

[image: localhost data]

here is the code of server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('employeelist',['employeelist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');//inserting data to server

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());//inserting data to server

app.get("/employeelist", function (req,res) {
    console.log("I received a GET Request")

    db.employeelist.find(function (err, docs) {
    console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.post('/employeelist', function (req,res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.employeelist.insert(req.body,function (err,doc) { // inserting data to mongodb
        res.json(doc);
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("server running on port 3000");
```

here is code of controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/employeelist'
    }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
        console.log("data recieved");
        $scope.employeelist=response.data;
    },function onError(error) {
            console.log("Unknown error");
            $scope.employeelist=error.data;
        });

    $scope.addEmployee = function () {
        console.log($scope.employee);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/employeelist'
    }).then(function Success(response) {
        console.log("Employee Added");
        $scope.employeelist = response.data;
    });
};
}]);
```

here is the code of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>Employees List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <h1>Employees List</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Designation</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="employee.name"</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="employee.designation"</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" ng-model="employee.salary"</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addEmployee()">Add Employee</button></button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employeelist">
                    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.designation}}</td>
                    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/
angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../controllers/controller.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after adding addemployee its getting printed in the console but not showing up in the employeelist

here is the browser console image
[image: here is browser console]

Comment: Are you actually asking *"Why are the new items being added with no other data?"*. Because if you take a look at your `$scope.addEmployee` you should notice that you are not actually submitting any data back to the server. Hence `req.body` is simply empty, leaving just the default `_id`. Perhaps you should actually send some data.

Comment: i did send some data but it stored in that way

Comment: No you have not. That's the point. There is no data payload attached to the request. All you do is a `console.log()`. That's not actually sending the data with the POST.

Comment: i just did it and it stored but not getting displayed

Comment: Talk is cheap. The code in your question shows no such thing. No-one here is looking over your shoulder. We cannot see what you do not show. You cannot just say you did something. You actually need to show what you are doing.

Comment: neil lunn i have added kindly check the question again

Comment: Dude. Please use your eyes. `$http({ method: 'POST', url: '/employeelist' }).then`. There is **no data being sent in that request**. Take a look at the [`$http` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers). You have no `data` block in your request. Therefore nothing is being sent.

Comment: then what could be the error.. why my added data not displaying

Comment: @neil lunn i solved my issue... n my eyes r clearly working well

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue by changing Http Post method and by adding refresh function

here are the changes i have done

```
var refresh = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/employeelist'
        }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
            console.log("data recieved");
            $scope.employeelist = response.data;
            $scope.employee = {};
        });
    };
    refresh();

    $scope.addEmployee = function () {
        console.log($scope.employee);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/employeelist',
        data:$scope.employee
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employee = {}; //Clear input box
        console.log('POST Response: '+ response.statusText);
        refresh();
    });
};
```